# How do I install the Ashmem and Binder kernel mods for Anbox?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

So, I need a virtual Android environment for some work I'm doing and decided to install Anbox. Unfortunately, it won't run because Ashmem and Binder are not installed. I've tried alternatives like Genymotion, but they just don't work due to limited RAM and CPU power, hence why I need something lighter like Anbox. I've also tried compiling the modules from the Anbox source code, but it doesn't work, which I'm told is because of a particular kernel call/ function that has been removed in newer kernels. I'm using Ubuntu 22 and I really hope someone can help me out. Any help will be highly appreciated.